# Create a completely self-contained gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing my first real gem. It depends on three gems, and those gems have roughly a dozen dependencies. I'd like this all to be self-contained so my gem will always use the dependencies from inside the gem, and will not require the other gems to be installed at the system level. Doable?

I played around with bundle install --path vendor --standalone. It did indeed store all the gems' source code into vendor, but I could then not get my 'requires' to work correctly and the code could not be found.

I suspect either that it's not possible to do this with a gem (only and app) or I was missing some piece of configuration to point my gem's code at the vendored dependencies. I played around with $LOADPATH but could not make it work.

Anyone know if this can be done and, if so, how to make it work? Pointers to info welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add those gems as a dependency to your .gemspec file. That way when your gem gets installed, its dependencies will also be installed.

More information can be found [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency)